# A good way to set a single container view to different custom UIViews?

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple different custom `UIView` classes, but all of them are using the same basic appearance such a cancel button, title, rounded corners, shadows  .
I would like to create a single container with these features, and add the custom subviews above it.

The single option I see is to always *add that container*, and every time pass it with a different custom subview class:

```
//on container
func setWithView(view:customViewA) { }
```

but what if I need to pass **more arguments** to `customA` ? and also get **delegate** from it directly? everything will have to go through this container (bad design obviously)

Another way is to add the custom views as usual, and inside each of them add that container, problem with this that if I add the container above, I will have to set things like rounded corners and shadows on each custom subview (because the container is above it, not underneath ) and **lose the effect again**.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you create a custom UIView with all those controls, and subclass it several times for each use?

That way all the custom UIView classes will have what you need.

Create your subviews in "initWithFrame" methods, and when you create your subclass, just make sure to call the super class method, so each subclass will create the controls you want.

```
import UIKit

protocol SuperClassProtocol {
func buttonClicked()
}

class SuperClassView: UIView {

var button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
var delegate : SuperClassProtocol?

required init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func buttonTapped() {

}
}


class SubclassView1 : SuperClassView {

required init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame) // here it creates the button

    // add here more views
}
}

class SubclassView2 : SuperClassView {

required init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame) // here it creates the button

    // add here more views
}

override func buttonTapped() {
    self.delegate?.buttonClicked() // call protocol method from subclass
}
}
```

Comment: and what about delegates and other arguments that has to be sent to the parent view controller? Can you show a very simple structure example ? subclassing works great with data but I never get to understand how to do that with view hierarchy .

Comment: As long as you add it to the superclass, all subclasses will inheritance it. Both delegate or arguments.

Comment: Sorry I can't see how are you going to do so. If you can show a simple example how to create customViewA as subclass of containerView, and set customViewA with all the required arguments and delegates.

Comment: So maybe I didn't understand you... I added code block to make sure we understand each other...

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I was stupid enough to not thinking about it the right way. I got you.